# Laravel Datatable Data Display Issue

Tags: laravel, datatable

Below is my controller code. I have seen data in console and network tab ajax call but it is not displaying in view page table. Can someone please help me on this. Please tell me what i am doing wrong in this.

I have checked with static data passed directly on ajax call but also static data is not displaying too. but when i pass any string as static then it will display each character from string in different columns.

```
$finaldata = array();
foreach($reportDetails as $agentReportColumnKey => $agentReportColumnValue){
    $tempfinaldata = array();

    $tempfinaldata['Customer Name'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->name) ? $agentReportColumnValue->name : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Number'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->tel) ? $agentReportColumnValue->tel : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Email'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->email) ? $agentReportColumnValue->email : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['DOB'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->signUpQuestionDetails->birthDay) ? $agentReportColumnValue->signUpQuestionDetails->birthDay : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Debt Level'] = $agentReportColumnValue->debtLevel->sum('amountOwned') ? $agentReportColumnValue->debtLevel->sum('amountOwned') : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Total Debt'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->quickSolution[0]->totalDebts) ? $agentReportColumnValue->quickSolution[0]->totalDebts : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Employment'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->signUpQuestionDetails->EmpStatus) ? $agentReportColumnValue->signUpQuestionDetails->EmpStatus : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Living Arrangements'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->signUpQuestionDetails->rentOrOwnHome) ? $agentReportColumnValue->signUpQuestionDetails->rentOrOwnHome : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Downloaded Date'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->userSignInDate) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($agentReportColumnValue->userSignInDate)) : '-';
    if(strtolower($agentReportColumnValue->zCaseType) == 'completed') {
    $tempfinaldata['Completed Date'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->userStatusUpdatedDate) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($agentReportColumnValue->userStatusUpdatedDate)) : '-';
    } else {
    $tempfinaldata['Completed Date'] = '-';
    }
    $tempfinaldata['Case Status'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->zCaseType) ? $agentReportColumnValue->zCaseType : '-';
    $tempfinaldata['Solution Type'] = isset($agentReportColumnValue->UserSolution->solutionType) ? $agentReportColumnValue->UserSolution->solutionType : '-';

    $finaldata[] = $tempfinaldata;
}

$totalRecords = UserNames::select('count(*) as allcount')->count();
$totalRecordswithFilter = UserNames::select('count(*) as allcount')->where('name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')->count();

return [
    'aaData' => $finaldata,
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordswithFilter,

];
```

Below is my view file code.

```
        $('document').ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type : 'POST',
                url  : '{{ route('report.full_report_ajax_data') }}',
                //dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success :  function(result) {
                    //pass data to datatable
                    console.log(result); // just to see I'm getting the correct data.
                    $('#full_report').DataTable({
                        "searching": false, //this is disabled because I have a custom search.
                        //"aaData": [result], //here we get the array data from the ajax call.
                        "aaData": [result], //here we get the array data from the ajax call.
                        //"bProcessing": true,
                        "aoColumns": [
                          { "sTitle": "Customer Name" },
                          { "sTitle": "Number" },
                          { "sTitle": "Email" },
                          { "sTitle": "DOB" },
                          { "sTitle": "Debt Level" },
                          { "sTitle": "Total Debt" },
                          { "sTitle": "Employment" },
                          { "sTitle": "Living Arrangements" },
                          { "sTitle": "Downloaded Date" },
                          { "sTitle": "Completed Date" },
                          { "sTitle": "Case Status" },
                          { "sTitle": "Solution Type" },
                        ] //this isn't necessary unless you want modify the header
                          //names without changing it in your html code. 
                          //I find it useful tho' to setup the headers this way.
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```